# Replacement of QVariant and setAttributeMap in PyQGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, pyqgis

I am updating a plugin for QGIS 1.8 to QGIS 2.x. I have the code below.

1. The setAttributeMap does not exist anymore. I have replaced it with fet.setAttributes and it seems to work.
2. When using  fet.setAttributes({0:QVariant(fid}), I get the error:

PyQt4.QtCore.QVariant represents a mapped type and cannot be instantiated.

I have tried to just remove the QVariant() and used fet.setAttributes({0:fid}), but then I get the error:

TypeError: QgsFeature.setAttributes(list-of-attributes): argument 1 has unexpected type 'dict'

The code worked well with 1.8, so what can I do to replace QVariant or setAttributeMap? I think it could be something with changing setAttributeMap to setAttributes

```
vl = QgsVectorLayer("MultiLineString", layerName, "memory")
pr = vl.dataProvider()
vl.startEditing()
pr.addAttributes([QgsField("id", QVariant.Int)])
fet = QgsFeature()
addRange = northRange * math.tan(abs(math.radians(bearing)))
noPoints = ((eastRange + addRange) / projEast) + 1
for i in range(0,int(math.ceil(noPoints)), 1):
    fet.setGeometry( QgsGeometry.fromMultiPolyline( [[ QgsPoint(minE + offset + (projEast * i) ,minN), QgsPoint(minE + offset + (projEast * i) - addRange,maxN) ]] ))
    fet.setAttributeMap({0:QVariant(fid)})
    pr.addFeatures( [ fet ] )
    fid = fid + 1
vl.commitChanges()
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(vl)
```

---

I have change my code to:

```
vl = QgsVectorLayer("MultiLineString", layerName, "memory")
pr = vl.dataProvider()
vl.startEditing()
pr.addAttributes([QgsField("id", QVariant.Int)])
fet = QgsFeature()
fields = vl.pendingFields()
fet.setFields( fields, True )
addRange = northRange * math.tan(abs(math.radians(bearing)))
noPoints = ((eastRange + addRange) / projEast) + 1
for i in range(0,int(math.ceil(noPoints)), 1):
    fet.setGeometry( QgsGeometry.fromMultiPolyline( [[ QgsPoint(minE + offset + (projEast * i) ,minN), QgsPoint(minE + offset + (projEast * i) - addRange,maxN) ]] ))
    fet['id'] = fid
    pr.addFeatures( [ fet ] )
    fid = fid + 1
vl.commitChanges()
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(vl)
```

but I still need to make an attribute named 'id' I guess before it works. If I use the *setAttributes* function it includes a QVariant which I am not allowed to do!

Or is it me who does not understand.

---

This is the final code, and it is working:

```
vl = QgsVectorLayer("MultiLineString", layerName, "memory")
vl.startEditing()
vl.addAttribute(QgsField("id", QVariant.Int))
fet = QgsFeature()
fields = vl.pendingFields()
fet.setFields( fields, True )
addRange = northRange * math.tan(abs(math.radians(bearing)))
noPoints = ((eastRange + addRange) / projEast) + 1
for i in range(0,int(math.ceil(noPoints)), 1):
    fet.setGeometry( QgsGeometry.fromMultiPolyline( [[ QgsPoint(minE + offset + (projEast * i) ,minN), QgsPoint(minE + offset + (projEast * i) - addRange,maxN) ]] ))
    fet['id'] = fid
    vl.addFeatures( [ fet ] )
    fid = fid + 1
vl.commitChanges()
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(vl)
```

Comment: https://hub.qgis.org/wiki/17/Python_plugin_API_changes_from_18_to_20#Remove-QVariant-calls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can still use `QVariant` but don't use it as a type.

E.g. the following is still fine:

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import QVariant
vl.startEditing()
vl.addAttribute(QgsField("id", QVariant.Int))
```

However, it is no longer required (and no longer allowed) to use `QVariant` as a datatype. This means, instead of `QVariant(fid)` you should just use `fid`. You already have posted a link to the relevant section in the API changes.

The API also changed in terms of [vector layer handling](https://hub.qgis.org/wiki/17/Python_plugin_API_changes_from_18_to_20#Gettingsetting-QgsFeature-attributes-simplified), which can be confused with the changes concerning `QVariant` but it's a different pair of shoes.

The relevant code for this is:

```
fet = QgsFeature()
fields = vl.pendingFields()
fet.setFields( fields, True )
fet['id'] = 42
```

And a minor note:

- If you directly work on the dataprovider ( `pr.addFeatures()`, `pr.addAttributes()`) there is no need to toggle layer editing ( `vl.startEditing()`, `vl.commitChanges()`). If you want an undo stack, use the `QgsVectorLayer` methods instead of the `QgsVectorDataProvider` methods (i.e. by using `vl.[method]` instead of `pr.[method]`. If you work directly on the dataprovider, another caveat is, that events (updated features...) may not be propagated properly and lead to inconsistencies in the representation (attribute table...). **TL;DR: Use `vl.addFeature()` instead of `pr.addFeatures()`**

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. It helped a bit. Although the `fet.initFields( fields, True )` is not possible. It gives the error: 'AttributeError: 'QgsFeature' object has no attribute 'initFields''.

Comment: sorry, it is `setFields()`. My mistake.

Comment: I have added my new code at the top, but I can not make the `fet['id'] = 42' work.

Comment: You will still need to add a field to the layer. Either use `pr.addAttributes()` and a subsequent `vl.updateFields()` or `vl.addAttribute()`

Comment: I can still not make it work. I have added the `pr.addAttributes` in my code at the top, but I still do not understand how to add an attribute. I can not make `vl.updateFields()` or `vl.addAttribute()`.

Comment: I made it work. The working code is at the top. Thank you so much for the help.

Comment: Nice. If the answer solved your question, please mark it as correct by clicking the button left of the answer.